# How to setup a CNAME (alias) for a machine on my home network

Tags: networking, dns

I want to do this to:

- test name based virtual hosting
- provide friendly machine names to other users of the network.

My home network is behind a Synology RT1900AC router if that is relevant. What options do I have to give aliases to local machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it is a home network, so I assume not too many hosts, I would change the hosts file on the local machines. It is not an elegant way but it is a working one. As your router seems to have a DNS package available to [download](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/app_packages/DNSServer) per [manual p.29](http://www.sws.cz/prod_img/synology/syno_usersguide_routerrt1900ac_enu.pdf), this would be a nicer way, unfortunately I never set up one of those. But I assume it will add a nice GUI to the administration portal.

Comment: I installed the DNS package, and followed this manual https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=233&t=67565 and it doesn work

Comment: As told in my answer - I never set up a router with an additional DNS package. I would go with the local hosts files within a small home network (less than 10). As you did not describe how your home network looks like, another solution could be to setup a VM which would act as a primary DNS server and would forward DNS request to another DNS (router DNS or eg google DNS). All workstations should be setup with two DNS servers (first the VM, when unavailable go to second DNS server) - a bit more messy solution.